# Access violation using LocalAlloc()

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, memory-management

I have a Visual Studio 2008 Windows Mobile 6 C++ application that is using an API that requires the use of `LocalAlloc()`. To make my life easier, I created an implementation of a standard allocator that uses LocalAlloc() internally:

```
/// Standard library allocator implementation using LocalAlloc and LocalReAlloc 
/// to create a dynamically-sized array. 
/// Memory allocated by this allocator is never deallocated. That is up to the
/// user.
template< class T, int max_allocations > 
class LocalAllocator
{
public:
    typedef T         value_type;
    typedef size_t    size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T*        pointer;
    typedef const T*  const_pointer;
    typedef T&        reference;
    typedef const T&  const_reference;

    pointer address( reference r ) const { return &r; };
    const_pointer address( const_reference r ) const { return &r; };

    LocalAllocator() throw() : c_( NULL )
    {
    };

    /// Attempt to allocate a block of storage with enough space for n elements
    /// of type T. n>=1 && n<=max_allocations.
    /// If memory cannot be allocated, a std::bad_alloc() exception is thrown.
    pointer allocate( size_type n, const void* /*hint*/ = 0 )
    {
        if( NULL == c_ )
        {   
            c_ = LocalAlloc( LPTR, sizeof( T ) * n );
        }
        else
        {
            HLOCAL c = LocalReAlloc( c_, sizeof( T ) * n, LHND );
            if( NULL == c )
                LocalFree( c_ );
            c_ = c;
        }
        if( NULL == c_ )
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        return reinterpret_cast< T* >( c_ );
    };

    /// Normally, this would release a block of previously allocated storage.
    /// Since that's not what we want, this function does nothing.
    void deallocate( pointer /*p*/, size_type /*n*/ )
    {
        // no deallocation is performed. that is up to the user.
    };

    /// maximum number of elements that can be allocated
    size_type max_size() const throw() { return max_allocations; };

private:
    /// current allocation point
    HLOCAL c_;
}; // class LocalAllocator
```

My application is using that allocator implementation in a std::vector<>

```
#define MAX_DIRECTORY_LISTING 512

std::vector< WIN32_FIND_DATA, 
    LocalAllocator< WIN32_FIND_DATA, MAX_DIRECTORY_LISTING > > file_list;

WIN32_FIND_DATA find_data = { 0 };
HANDLE find_file = ::FindFirstFile( folder.c_str(), &find_data );
if( NULL != find_file )
{
    do 
    {
        // access violation here on the 257th item.
        file_list.push_back( find_data );
    } while ( ::FindNextFile( find_file, &find_data ) );

    ::FindClose( find_file );
}

// data submitted to the API that requires LocalAlloc()'d array of WIN32_FIND_DATA structures
SubmitData( &file_list.front() );
```

On the 257th item added to the vector<>, the application crashes with an access violation:

```
Data Abort: Thread=8e1b0400 Proc=8031c1b0 'rapiclnt'
AKY=00008001 PC=03f9e3c8(coredll.dll+0x000543c8) RA=03f9ff04(coredll.dll+0x00055f04) BVA=21ae0020 FSR=00000007
First-chance exception at 0x03f9e3c8 in rapiclnt.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01ae0020.
```

`LocalAllocator::allocate` is called with an `n=512` and `LocalReAlloc()` succeeds. The actual Access Violation exception occurs within the std::vector<> code after the `LocalAllocator::allocate` call:

```
     0x03f9e3c8    
     0x03f9ff04    
>    MyLib.dll!stlp_std::priv::__copy_trivial(const void* __first = 0x01ae0020, const void* __last = 0x01b03020, void* __result = 0x01b10020) Line: 224, Byte Offsets: 0x3c    C++
     MyLib.dll!stlp_std::vector<_WIN32_FIND_DATAW,LocalAllocator<_WIN32_FIND_DATAW,512> >::_M_insert_overflow(_WIN32_FIND_DATAW* __pos = 0x01b03020, _WIN32_FIND_DATAW& __x = {...}, stlp_std::__true_type& __formal = {...}, unsigned int __fill_len = 1, bool __atend = true) Line: 112, Byte Offsets: 0x5c    C++
     MyLib.dll!stlp_std::vector<_WIN32_FIND_DATAW,LocalAllocator<_WIN32_FIND_DATAW,512> >::push_back(_WIN32_FIND_DATAW& __x = {...}) Line: 388, Byte Offsets: 0xa0    C++
     MyLib.dll!Foo(unsigned long int cbInput = 16, unsigned char* pInput = 0x01a45620, unsigned long int* pcbOutput = 0x1dabfbbc, unsigned char** ppOutput = 0x1dabfbc0, IRAPIStream* __formal = 0x00000000) Line: 66, Byte Offsets: 0x1e4    C++
```

If anybody can point out what I may be doing wrong, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,
PaulH

Comment: I told you last week that you shouldn't use `LHND` with `LocalReAlloc` when you really mean `LMEM_MOVEABLE | LMEM_ZEROINIT`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784264/localalloc-and-localrealloc-usage They're the same numeric value, but they don't mean the same things, and when you mix constants with different meanings, you confuse the people who are familiar with their real meanings, like Heath.

Comment: @Rob - Yes, you did. I somehow missed reading your last comment on the topic. I'll make that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first thought your problem was the parameter `LHND` to `LocalReAlloc()` -- you should usually not pass that parameter to that function.

The actual problem is that you should not even be calling that function.  The `vector` implementation reallocates its own memory.  A C++ standard allocator does not provide reallocation.

You should implement:

```
template<typename T> class LocalAllocator {
...
pointer allocate(sizetype s)
{
    pointer p = reinterpret_cast<pointer>(LocalAlloc(LPTR, s * sizeof(T)));

    if (NULL == p)
        throw std::bad_alloc();

    return p;
}

void deallocate(pointer p, sizetype)    
{
    LocalFree(reinterpret_cast<LHND>(p));
}
...
}
```

Something similar to that should work.

There is no need for you to keep track of the pointer -- it will be provided back to you at a call to `deallocate()`, that is the responsibility of your API client, the `vector<T>` implementation.

Comment: According to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908783(v=MSDN.10).aspx: *If LocalReAlloc reallocates a fixed object, the value of the handle returned is the address of the first byte of the memory block. To access the memory, a process can cast the return value to a pointer.* Also, LocalLock() is not supported on Windows Mobile.

Comment: That is true, Paul, and I find nothing to disagree with in the bit you quoted.  That bit does not bear on my original point: you should not pass LHND, rather than zero, to LocalReAlloc().  You don't want an LHND, you want a relocated LPTR.  Except, as you can read in my revised answer, you should not be calling ReAlloc at all.

Comment: @Heath - Your implementation works except that I still need the data in the vector to be allocated when the vector itself goes out of scope. That was why i had `deallocate()` empty before.

Comment: @PaulH - OK, well do not do that, lol.  But if you are feeling dirty, the compiler and system will not immediately punish you if you do not call LocalFree().  Eventually, you will run out of memory.  Your program is alloted a portion of a finite amount of memory -- failure to return the memory to the system when done with it is called a 'memory leak.'  You can choose to leave deallocate() empty, but your system will leak memory until it eventually fails.

Comment: @PaulH - 100 times better is to figure out how to properly specify the scope of the vector<T> to the portion of the program where it is used.  Then, it can be 'cleaned up' (the memory returned to the system) when its use has concluded.

Comment: @Heath - LocalFree() will be called by the API I'm passing the data to. The idea is to NOT leak memory and still get the benefits of using a `std::vector<>`

Comment: @PaulH - Sounds byzantine but if you do it on purpose, I approve.

Comment: Heath, LocalReAlloc on Windows Mobile doesn't support memory handles, but it still requires LMEM_MOVEABLE if it's supposed to be allowed to allocate a new block of memory instead of just growing its current block. (Without that flag, the API will fail even if there's plenty of memory in the heap but none available adjacent to the current block.) Since Paul also wants the new memory zeroed, he uses LHND since that constant happens to be numerically equal to the combination of LMEM_MOVEABLE and LMEM_ZEROINIT. See the link in my comment on the question above, which also explains Paul's API.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. When you allocate each next block, you free the currently used block. So all the pointers that pointed there become invalid. I doubt this is what vector expects from an allocator.

Comment: That is not how realloc() works at all -- look it up.  realloc() copies the old data if moving the address of the block is required.  See LocalReAlloc() for the MS docs which may address the point, but are consistent with standard C library realloc() on this point.

Comment: Heath - yes, but is vector aware that all its old data was moved when it tries to allocate a new block?

Comment: I thought the block you highlighted looked suspicious...  But it results in throwing the bad_alloc exception, because c_ will be NULL.  But the LHND parameter is wrong.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're saying there is no way to use a LocalAlloc() based allocator with std::vector<>?

Comment: you are correct about the vector<T> implementation not expecting a reallocation to occur.  See my revised answer.  The use of LHND to LocalReAlloc() is still wrong, but the problem is the very use of LocalReAlloc().  A C++ allocator just returns a new memory block each call to allocate().  It is the vector<T> implementation which manages the allocated storage, in terms of a reallocation.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Igor Krivokon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806831/access-violation-using-localalloc/2806888#2806888), each call to `allocate()` possibly invalidates all the pointers returned by previous calls to `allocate()`. This is not how an allocator is supposed to work and will most probably result in undefined behavior:

For example when the vector needs to allocate a new bigger piece of memory, it will copy the data from the "old" memory to the "new" one returned by `allocate()`. Then it will destroy all the objects in the "old" memory and free it.

If *old* and *new* now are the same memory locations, copy construction of the "new" objects and the following destruction of the "old" objects will get all messed up. On the other hand, if *old* is not valid anymore (because it got reallocated), the vector will access invalid memory.

*And another point:* Allocators have to be copy-constructible. If a copy is constructed from your allocator and then both are used to allocate further elements, `LocalReAlloc()` will be called on the same pointer twice. So you would need to provide a custom copy constructor that avoids this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also, I will add the copy-ctor as you suggest.